# Can a StringRequest be created inside a doInBackground() method?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-volley

I am creating a button which when clicked calls the `checkUserName` method which searches the database and tells whether the username is available or not. The `URL_CHECK_USERNAME` responds "Username Available" or "Username not available".

```
    public void checkUserName(View v){

        String username = inputUserName.getText().toString().trim();
        new CheckUsername().execute(username);

    }

    class CheckUsername extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

        String r = null;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(RegisterActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Checking Availability of this Username...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            //String r = null;
            final String username = params[0];

            StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST,
                    AppConfig.URL_CHECK_USERNAME, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    r = response;
                }

            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

                    Log.e(TAG, "Error in checking username." + volleyError.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), volleyError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    hideDialog();
                }
            }){
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams()  {

                    Map<String, String> param = new HashMap<>();
                    //param.put("username", params[0]);
                    param.put("username", username);
                    return param;
                }
            };


            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq);

            return r;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            pDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
```

This program displays an empty Toast everytime. What can be the problem?

Comment: Does that even compile?  Looks like you've commented out where r is declared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code you posted I suppose you are using Volley as your network library.
If that's the case you should be aware that there's no need for that Asynctask of yours because Volley takes care of the threading for you.

The request will be executed in the background and the callback will be called asynchronously. That 's why your toasts are empty.

Create your StringRequest in your checkUsername(View) method and have the toast shown in the onResponse callback.

Comment: I didn't get your second para. Why are the toasts empty? @Avsector

Comment: Look up "asynchronous processing" if you don't know what that is, because you should understand that in order to do what you're trying to do.  Once you understand that, you should see that the `doInBackground` method returns immediately, before the HTTP request happens, leaving nothing for the toast to display.